# How to Create a branch named after an issue, from 'other branch' but not 'master' in GitLab site

Tags: gitlab

[Screenshot of GitLab UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhZt8.png)

By default it will create a branch named after the issue from 'master'. But is there any way to create that branch from other branch other than master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rebase this branch on the expected branch on CLI :

```
git checkout <issue-branch>
git rebase master --onto <expected-branch>
```